# I want to run an angular project which I have downloaded from github. But I see there are several dependency errors

Tags: angular

Can anyone help me in how to run the application ?

all the import pacakages I see are underlined as errors.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {SearchRecipeComponent} from './search-recipe/search-recipe.component';
import {ShoppingListComponent} from './shopping-list/shopping-list.component';
```

Comment: Please add more information such as the GitHub project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First delete node modules folder and then try to run

```
npm install
```

and then clean and rebuild the project,

now run

```
ng serve --o
```